# Is it possible to have in Lubuntu 12.04 the new Keyboard Layout Handler of 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, lxpanel

Lubuntu 12.10 has a new version of LXPanel (0.5.11) and a new "Keyboard Layout Handler" with more settings than the older "Keyboard Layout Switcher".

12.04 "Keyboard Layout Switcher" settings:

[image]

12.10 "Keyboard Layout Handler" settings:

[image]

which include adding new keyboard

[image]

**Is it possible to use this new Keyboard Layout Handler in 12.04 (which has LXPanel 0.5.8?) - and should first update the LXPanel? Is this update possible in 12.04?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems that the new application is available as part of a lxpanel 0.5.10 .deb version for 12.04, [here](http://www.giuspen.com/customs/)**.

The 0.5.11 version of LXPanel is available for Precise as deb [here](https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/+archive/lubuntu-daily/+build/4218248) - but gives this error while trying to install with gdebi:
[image]

But libmenu-cache2 appears available only for Raring 13.04. Installing that in Precise and then the latest LXPanel is possible but it may be safer to stay with LXPanel 0.5.10 in Precise until update from official sources. About that dependency see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/244648/47206).)