# How to install new LXPanel in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, versions, lxpanel

Lubuntu 12.04 has LXPanel 0.5.8, while Lubuntu 12.10 has LXPanel 0.5.11, which has enhanced features - see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/240868/47206).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Keyboard Layout Handler" which is [the major enhancement](https://askubuntu.com/q/240868/47206) compared to the older "Keyboard Layout Switcher" of LXPanel 0.5.8 is present in [this](http://www.giuspen.com/customs/) 0.5.10 build of LXPanel.

Trying to install LXPanel 0.5.11 daily build for Precise, it seems to ask for libmenu-cache2, which is available only for Raring 13.04. I have installed  libmenu-cache2 in Precise, then  this dev build of LXPanel 0.5.11. But then, staying with LXPanel 0.5.10 for the moment in Precise seems safer, at least until I find an answer to [the question whether it is safe to install libmenu-cache2](https://askubuntu.com/q/244648/47206)  .

Comment: how is this an answer?

Comment: @Ysangkok: sorry, initially i was about to edit the answer and pressed to publish by mistake. i have edited the answer, but also i am forced to change/edit the question because in its initial form it asked for an answer that could lead people in installing dependencies that were not made for precise 12.04 and could badly affect their system. i have created a question on that (http://askubuntu.com/q/244618/47206). now the question and answer are different and will try to improve them after i learn more about all this