# Why LXPanel 0.5.11 asks for a new dependency in Precise but not in Quantal?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, lubuntu, lxpanel, 13.04

LXPanel 0.5.11 that is default in Lubuntu Quantal has [enhanced features](https://askubuntu.com/q/240868/47206) compared to the older version that is default in Lubuntu Precise (0.5.8).

The new version of LXPanel is [available for Precise](https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/+archive/lubuntu-daily/+build/4218248). But while installing that in Precise 12.04, it asks for `libmenu-cache2` (that seems available only for Raring 13.04).

Installing that `libmenu-cache2` in Precise would allow installing LXPanel 0.5.11 (for Precise). (But is it safe to install this `libmenu-cache2` for Raring in 12.04? should it replace libmenu-cache1 there? it does not by default.)

The odd thing is that in a different computer with Lubuntu Quantal I see that LXPanel 0.5.11 works with only `libmenu-cache1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with **the way the version of a build (especially dev version) is displayed**.

In Lubuntu Quantal, the LXPanel version that works with only `libmenu-cache1` is displayed  as

[image]

But in Synaptic Manager it's 0.5.10:

[image]

Also,

```
~$ apt-cache policy lxpanel
lxpanel:
  Installed: 0.5.10+git20120823-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.5.10+git20120823-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.5.10+git20120823-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I do not know how Launchpad displayed the name of this version, but it could be a dev or otherwise improved version of 0.5.10, although I do not remember manually updating LXPanel in Quantal.

Also, after installing (in Lubuntu Precise) LXPanel for Precise from [here](https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/+archive/lubuntu-daily/+build/4218248), which looks like being a daily build of 0.5.11 (Launchpad named it lxpanel-dev-0.5.11~bzr1306+201301150740~precise1) (which was possible only after installing  `libmenu-cache2` for Raring from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/libmenu-cache2/download)) I see that LXPanel "About" says version 0.5.12, while in Synaptic it was displayed 0.5.11.

So, the  dev version installed in Precise **is not the same version as the one from the other computer running Quantal**, but a newer build that asks for libmenu-cache2, while that quantal version does not.

---

It seems that **LXPanel versions above 0.5.10 need `libmenu-cache2`.**

(But to see the real version of a build one must look in Synaptic or run `apt-cache policy lxpanel`, because dev builds might show a newer version in "About" section.)